# How would I get a value from a csv file and use it as a parameter in a sql task in ssis

Tags: ssis

I need to use the date inside of my CSV to pass to a SQL Task. Right now I parse it from the file name but the vendor sent a file that did not conform to my parsing and I ended up with duplicate records as it could not delete passed on the variable. How can I do this? Can I do it in a script? If so can I get some examples?

Comment: You can import the SQL file into a stage/temp table, then select the values from the stage/temp table into your variables.

Comment: We need more information to reproduce your issue. It sounds like you will always? parse a date value from the file name but maybe you need a fall back to extracting a value from the file contents? I'm certain the problem is clear in your mind but it's hazy from where I read your problem definition

Comment: Brad, I could I was just hoping there was a better way inside of SSIS code.

Comment: Billinkc, Yes I was reading it off of the file name and then the vendor to send a file with "_Test" on the end and as I use the date for deleting any previous information for that day, I got duplicate as the where statement ended up with = 'Te/st/10' and of course did not delete anything.